# Source of CandidatesView Candidates in Android

Tags: android, android-userdictionary

Can someone tell me where the candidates come from on android's CandidatesView while typing. And where are the words that we(user) taps to save are stored and how to access them programmatically?

I have searched the user dictionary but it does not store the words that user taps to save in phone(so that next time it may appear while typing)